# Excel 2010-line graph not displaying data as desired

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I will to plot a line graph of year vs. sales on excel 2010. However, the years are displaying on the y-axis wihile nothing but 1,2,3 etc is displaying on the x-axis.... Anybody might know what the problem is?

Comment: Would you mind showing us how your Excel sheet is set up and how you configured the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Put years (x values) into a column, and the y values into the next column. Put a label in the cell just above the top Y value, and keep the cell just above the top X value blank. Select this range and make an XY chart.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the line chart type, and not the xy scatter:

1. Select only the sales column (together with the title)
2. Go to insert, and select line chart
3. You will now have a chart with sales on the y-axis and 1, 2, 3... on the x-axis
4. Right-click on the chart -> select data
5. On the right side, under horizontal (category) axis labels, click edit, and select the range containing your years (without the title). Voila!